# Funcion Ajax no muestra el mensaje

Tags: ajax

tengo esta funcion en ajax que guarda bien los datos, pero le mensaje no lo muestra y no se que es, en consola no me muestra errores ni nada.

```
$.ajax({
    url: params,
    type: "POST",
    data: datos
    }).done(function(r) {
        if(r.r == true ) {
            $('#msj_user').html(r.msg).addClass("text-success").removeClass("text-danger").text("Registro Ingresado");
            //Hide it after 3 seconds
               setTimeout(function(){
               $('#msj_user').html(".");
               $.LoadingOverlay("show");
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $.LoadingOverlay("show");
                    location.reload();

                    }, 2000);
                            }, 3000);
                    } else {
                        $('#msj_user').html(r.msg).addClass("text-danger").removeClass("text-success");
                    }
                });
            return false;
```

Comment: Hola. No veo que indiques el formato de respuesta, de modo que `r` posiblemente no tenga los atributos que tratas de usar. Prueba a cambiar el color de algún DIV antes de `if(r.r == 'true')` y luego otro color a otro elemento al iniciar el bloque. Si sólo colorea el primero (es de esperar) r es texto plano y necesitas llevarlo a json o al formato que esperas.

Comment: de hecho puse un console.log antes del if y no salio nada

Comment: Dices que del lado del servidor hace actualización, de modo que : ¿revisaste la preparación de la salida a devolver?, puede estar ahí la dificultad.

Comment: Debieras presentar la parte de código que se ejecuta inmediatamente después de actualizar datos para revisarla

Comment: Si no se ejecutó el `console.log` del que hablas en el comentario es claro que hay error porque no está entrando en `.done()`. De modo que convendría implementar `.fail(function() { ... });` para verificar que hubo fallo y eventualmente mostrar algo que te oriente.

Comment: desde consola revise la data en xhr y el error venia de otro archivo php. gracias por los comentarios

Comment: Si. Me alegra que lo hayas encontrado. El código que mostrabas no tiene errores. de modo que el error tenía que estar en algún php que "abortaba" la respuesta.